# Making "sudo npm install --save-dev gulp" in Maverics nothing's happens

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to test Gulp and I find this problem.

- I installed Gulp globally with: `sudo npm install -g gulp`.
- Then I was created the folder: `mkdir my-gulp`
- `cd my-gulp`
- And the I try to do this: `sudo npm install --save-dev gulp`
- It seems work fine, no errors, but my folder `my-gulp` continues empty.
- I can see in console, this line:
  `gulp@3.8.6 ../../node_modules/gulp`
  And I thinkig the problem is here "`../../`", I think it must be "`gulp@3.8.6 node_modules/gulp`"

What do you think? Maybe is something about $PATH?

Comment: Can you run `which gulp` please ?

Comment: What happens when you add a package.json file to `my-gulp` just containing {} ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should **never** run `npm` via `sudo` for local packages.  (In fact, you shouldn't run it as root ever, but that's a different, more complex issue to solve.)

Second, you need to initialize NPM before you can install packages.  It sounds like you didn't do this.

There's two ways:

1. If you have an existing `package.json`, which contains the required information about a project, you can copy it into your folder, then edit in a text editor of your choice to get started.  If the `package.json` includes existing dependencies, you can either remove them, or run `npm i` in the folder to install them.
2. If you are starting fresh, run [`npm init`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-init.html) to set up a new package.

Once you have a valid `package.json`, you can install packages into your application.

---

As to why you are seeing `../../gulp`, I'm guessing you have a `package.json` further up the file tree somewhere.